# R googleVis gvisMotionChart set colorvar to Unique Colours?

Tags: r, googlevis

I am calling `gvisMotionChart` from the R package `googleVis` and I would like to set the `colorvar` parameter to `"Unique colours"`. I tried `colorvar="Unique colours"` but it doesn't work for me.

I would also like to set it to `select=All` by default, although I am not sure if this option can be passed on right now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would setting `colorvar` to the same variable as `idvar` do the trick?

Comment: @Codoremifa, it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass a list of options to gvisMotionChart command, like this

```
..., options=list(state='{"colorOption":"_UNIQUE_COLOR"};')
```

I don't know if there is an option for selecting all items. I usually select a couple of them, using `iconKeySettings` in the state definition, like  this:

```
"iconKeySettings":[{"key":{"dim0":"actual"}},{"key":{"dim0":"baseline"}}]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the version 0.6.1. It seems that passing anything to state= corrupts it and sets it to arbitrary values. As a workaround, I simply duplicated my idvar into another column and passed this new column to colorvar. e.g. d$color <- d$id and then pass colorvar="color".